# How do you create and update an iceberg table via polars/arrow?

Tags: python, python-polars, apache-iceberg

So far I've been happy with using parquet as the data format to persist my data, but I'm being encouraged to try iceberg as an alternative approach.

Keen to give it a go, but not sure how to start.

let's say I have a `polars` dataframe in Python:

```py
import polars as pl 
df = pl.DataFrame({'x':[1]})
```

How can I persist it as an iceberg table in disk (or blob storage)?

Polars can read iceberg tables, so for now I'm mainly trying to get to the write step.

Note that I'm happy to write via another library (`pyarrow` or `pyiceberg` I suppose) - but it's not clear what's the best way to do it.

Comment: I came across this: https://github.com/apache/iceberg-python/issues/23 - seems pyiceberg is adding write support soon

Answer (score 1):

You can't currently, Iceberg write functionality in pyIceberg isn't complete yet, (soon, I think). Once that is created then all libraries can use that to add Iceberg write functionality to things like Polars and DuckDB.

So right now to right from python you can only do so by sending a query to a java based query engine like Dremio, Spark, etc. (The Java Iceberg libraries do have writes)

For example in pyArrow you could connect to an Arrow supporting engine like Dremio and send CREATE and INSERT SQL statements. I cover this in this article:

https://www.dremio.com/blog/connecting-to-dremio-using-apache-arrow-flight-in-python/